# add column on a nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Is it possible to add a column on a nested relationship ?

For example, i have the following tables

```
groups
- id
- title

categories
- id
- title
- parent_id
- group_id

threads
- id
- title
- replies_count
- category_id
```

I want to do the following

```
class GroupController extends Controller {

public function index(){
return Groups::with(['categories'])->get()
}

class Category extends Model{

protected $withCount = ['threads'];
}
```

Therefore, when i eager-load the 'categories' i also eager-load each the threads associated with each category. But i want also to add a new column on the category model, with the some of the replies_count, the same as withCount.

For example

```
groups => [
"id" => 1,
"title" => "some-title"
"categories" => [
 "id" => 1,
 "title" => "category-title",
 "threads_count" => 2,
 "replies_count_sum" => 5
  ]
]
```

In the example above, the **group** with **id=1** has a **category** associated with it, and the category has **2 threads** associated with it and the total number of **replies** on these 2 threads are **5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do it using [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) and [sub Query Join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

```
$values=Group::with(['categories'=>function($query)use(
{
$repliesSumCountForCategory=Threads::selectRaw('category_id,sum(replies_count) as replies_count_sum')->groupBy('category_id');

   $query->withCount('threads');
   $query->join($repliesSumCountForCategory,'replies_sum_count_for_category',
function($join)
{
$join->on('categories.id','=','replies_sum_count_for_category.category_id')
}
$query->addSelect('replies_sum_count_for_category.replies_count_sum');
}
])->get();
```

i did not get the chance to test it, please let me know if it helps ...

Comment: i didn't try exactly your code but your approach helped me to make my queries work.